# How to verify JWT signature in PHP?

Tags: php, jwt, slim

I have a function that generates a JWT :

```
function getToken($user, $expTime){
   $jwt = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode([
     'iss' => request()->getBaseUrl(),
     'sub' => "{$user['id']}",
     'exp' => $expTime,
     'iat' => time(),
     'nbf' => time(),
     'is_admin' => $user['role_id'] == 1
 
  ], getenv("SECRET_KEY"), 'HS256');
 return $jwt;
}
```

This function returns the below token:

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJcL2FwaSIsInN1YiI6InVzNWIzY2M4YmRlMDc4MSIsImV4cCI6NTUxMDY1ODkyNDAwMCwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNzM4NTkwLCJuYmYiOjE1MzA3Mzg1OTAsImlzX2FkbWluIjpmYWxzZX0.3bMaxCaMprURZEDurnckZWSoDRp7ePMxZXDW0B6q6fk

When I use this token to make a request I get that:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "Signature verification failed"
}
```

To make it work I go to https://jwt.io/, add the key and verify it by passing the secret.

Then I get this token :

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIvYXBpIiwic3ViIjoidXM1YjNjYzhiZGUwNzgxIiwiZXhwIjo1NTEwNjU4OTI0MDAwLCJpYXQiOjE1MzA3Mzg1OTAsIm5iZiI6MTUzMDczODU5MCwiaXNfYWRtaW4iOmZhbHNlfQ.heF_L9LrFp7Hht2dbVtOMx_gdUtmPKzrMgxW1_jdWLo

And this works fine. But how to verify it with php code so I can send it to the user?

Code for response:

```
function loginUser($email, $password) {

    try {
        // Connecting to databas
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $user = findUserByEmail($email, $db);

        if(empty($user)){
            echo 'User not found';
            exit;
        }
        if(!password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
            echo 'Password does not match';
            exit;
        } 

        $expTime = time() * 3600;

        $jwt = getToken($user, $expTime);

        // Close databse
        $db = null;
        
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $jwt;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that send this response?

Comment: I updated the post so you can see the code.

Comment: Ok but, who send this message: `"message": "Signature verification failed"` ?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention. I use this framework https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth for the authentication system.  But I think it doesn't matter. The think is how to verify the key.

Comment: This message is sent from the framework when a request is made and the token is wrong.

Comment: So your code above produces a token without a signature? Isn't [`JWT::encode`](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) supposed to produce a complete token with signature?

Comment: I really don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: Turns out it was indeed the problem. Btw. it's called signing, no verifying. Verifying happens later, when your request contains a signed token. There might be another problem with your code. In  the JWT you show above the expiration time seems to be wrong: `"exp": 5510658924000`.

Comment: Yes I solve that too. I multiplied time() by 3600 instead of adding it so that gave me this huge number.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Could you ckeck at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107875/generate-jwt-with-user-information

Answer (score 1):

If you're landing on this page because of a "Signature verification failed" Google search, here is one thing to consider. I was getting this error because there were two spaces between "Bearer" and my token in the Authorization header.

Wrong:

```
Authorization:Bearer  eyJraWQiOiJDT2N...
```

Correct:

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJraWQiOiJDT2N...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I made it work by changing a little the function that generates the token:

```
function getToken($user, $expTime){
    $key = "secretkey";
    $token = array(
      'iss' => request()->getBaseUrl(),
      'sub' => "{$user['id']}",
      'exp' => $expTime,
      'iat' => time(),
      'nbf' => time(),
      'is_admin' => $user['role_id'] == 1
  );
  return JWT::encode($token, $key);
}
```